# Jqgrid selecting more than one row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, multi-select

My first question on SO! :) Thanks in advanced!

I'm having a problem with jqgrid multiple selection functionality.
I can only define a single multiple selection key and above that shift doesnt select more than 1 row into the collection at a time.

Any clue on a different grid plugin or a work around for this functionality?

Also, Does jqgrid have an option to hide the check boxes when multiselect is active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome on the stackoverflow.com!

You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717969/jqgrid-multiselect-behavior-when-pressing-special-key/3719637#3719637) some examples which shows live how different settings of jqGrid having `multiselect:true` works. All the option are [documented](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options).

You can look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186533/jqgrid-multiselect) another code which implement another musliselect behavior as standard. To tell the truth I don't tested the solution.To hide checkboxes you can use `$("#list").jqGrid('hideCol','cb');` because all checkboxes are placed in the column with the name 'cb'.

Mostly jqGrid are used together with the paging feature, so not many rows will be displayed at once and it is not a real problem to select many rows. Nevertheless I agree that the keybord support is not good enough in jqGrid. All other important functionality are on the other side so rich, that I don't see alternative plugin which I could recommend you. It is better to get jqGrid and write all what you need  additionally yourself. jqGrid has enough possibilities for extensibility.

Comment: Thank you - The examples you have provided have got me on the right track I think.